# canvas button onmouseover change color

Tags: javascript, canvas, onmouseover

I have a `drawButtons` function that takes an argument of "`nonhover`", "`hover1`" or "`hover2`" and draws up a new button set to the canvas, and depending on the argument it takes, will draw the buttons different colors. It does work when i call it from `setUpGame()` but not when I call it from `draw()`. I want to call it from draw() because `draw()` is called 80 times a second in `setInterval()`. That way it can keep checking if the mouse is hovering over the button and draw the appropriate button set.

`setUpGame()` is called outside of any object or function. `draw()` is called by `setInterval()` which is outside of any function or object. setInterval calls draw 80 times a second.

`getMouseOver()` another function that is the one that should actually be called by `draw()`, because it says "if mouse is over button one: drawButtons("hover1") and so on. It just doesn't draw the buttons when I call it.

There are no errors in the browser Javascript console. I am using Chrome which works best with my game.

From this we can deduce that there is no problem with `drawButtons()` as it worked when called from `setUpGame()`.

There is possibly a problem with `draw()` as `drawButtons()` doesn't work when I call it from there (but to perplex us more, displayNumbers does display the numbers when I call it from there) and it worked fine when playing the game (here we are not playing the game, we are on a start screen).

There is probably a problem with `getMouseOver()` because that doesn't work anywhere.

I will show you `getMouseOver()` for now. My program is getting big and it is overwhelming to show too much right from the start. I intend for this function to be called 80 times a second.

```
getMouseOver: function() {
    window.onload = (function(){
        window.onmouseover = function(e) {
            // IE doesn't always have e here
            e = e || window.event;

            // get event location

            // change the code so that it gives the relative location
            var location = {
            x: e.pageX - offset.x,
            y: e.pageY - offset.y
            };
            if (location.x > 103.5 && location.x < 265.5) {
                if (location.y > 240 && location.y < 291) {
                    nonGameContent.drawButtons("hover1");
                }
            }
            if (location.x > 103.5 && location.x < 265.5) {
                if (location.y > 160 && location.y < 212) {
                    nonGameContent.drawButtons("hover2");
                }
            }
            else{
                nonGameContent.drawButtons("nonHover");
            }
        }
    })},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this fiddle you have click() and onmousemove() that are working.
I didn't understand well if you want to display button at the beginning or just when the mouse hovers somewhere on the future place of the button but it's a beginning : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Akinaru/3a7g2/57/

Main modification :

```
 canvas.onmousedown = nonGameContent.getMouseClick;
 canvas.onmousemove = nonGameContent.getMouseOver;
```

Comment: I did for the drawRects (buttons) but not for the text in them (fillText)

Comment: If problem persists you can clear your canvas (canvas.width = canvas.width;) and redraw all your objects

Comment: this just in: the problem is definitely with getMouseOver() because i called drawButtons() from draw() and it works but i called getMouseOver() from draw() and it doesn't work. This is good progress. draw() clears the canvas before drawing.

Comment: draw() only works when called outside of any function, outside of set interval. It works when called in set interval for the gameplay but not the start screen. Weird.

Comment: Okay, did you enter good value for location.x and location.y to get to nonGameContent.drawButtons("hover1"); ?

Comment: yep, and if i didn't it would still call drawButtons("nonHover"), but it draws no buttons.

Comment: ok getMouseOver() was the last function of the nonGameContentObject but i had a comma after it by mistake. Now i am working on displaying the buttons but they won't display anymore even with drawButtons() when they used to. will update soon.

Comment: Yes the getMouseOver() is inside nonGameContent and i have used nonGameContent.getMouseOver(); when i call it. getMouseOver still won't work when drawButtons now does. Maybe because it is not being called in setInterval because draw in setInterval doesn't seem to work for the start screen. But if it's called just once it should still work once drawing "nonHover".

Comment: It draws "nonHover" when i move my mouse to a specific part of the screen. This would infer there is a problem with my x and y locations for mouseOver. But i checked them carefully.

Comment: Maybe if you create a fiddlejs we could debug this more efficiently.

Comment: I think this is all the code from my game you need to work it. If you try and get this going i will be very appreciative thanks you http://jsfiddle.net/3a7g2/

Comment: Ive set up this one to be like my code that does display "hover1" but it doesnt display in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3a7g2/9/

Comment: I have make button display by modifying window.onload statement but hover and click still dont work I am on it : http://jsfiddle.net/Akinaru/3a7g2/42/

Comment: Ok I found it you don't use onmouseover but onmousemove because onmouseover react only once so it stick to first value and you can't draw button

Comment: HAHAHA i just did that just before you answered and it worked. Thanks though! After all that, all i had to do was change the mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

to change the canvas rectangle color when you mouse over it use onmousemove to find if you are over it, then redraw the canvas with a different color rectangle

getMouseClick: function() {
        window.onmousemove = function(e) {